# SCALA LIFT - Model saved in mongo collection incorrectly

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

I have the following model:

```
class Mix private() extends MongoRecord[Mix] with ObjectIdPk[Mix] {

    def meta = Mix

    object title extends StringField(this, 50)
    object description extends StringField(this, 500)
    object link extends StringField(this, 250)
    object date extends DateField(this)

}

object Mix extends Mix with MongoMetaRecord[Mix]
```

Whenever I try and save a record, instead of saving in the collection "Mixes", it creates a new one called "Mixs" and populates that instead.

Is there something I should be defining to tell it to use the correctly named "Mixes" collection?

This seems to be an incorrect pluralization of the word mix, but am unsure how to correct it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoRecord simply adds an ‘s’ to your Object’s name and doesn’t know anything about other pluralisation rules. In order to fix this, you need to override

```
override def collectionName = "Mixes"
```

in `object Mix`.